# Pandas.read_csv() FileNotFoundError even though file exists

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv, file-io

I try to run this piece of Python 3 code in my Anaconda Jupyter Notebook (same cell, nothing else in):

```
train  = pd.read_csv('tutorial\labeledTrainData.tsv', header=0, delimiter="\t", quoting=3) #OK!
test   = pd.read_csv('tutorial\testData.tsv',         header=0, delimiter="\t", quoting=3) #FileNotFoundError!
```

the first line runs just fine, but the second one gives error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'tutorial\testData.tsv' does not exist: b'tutorial\testData.tsv'
```

**dir** command in the respective **tutorial** folder gives:

```
06.12.2019  15:38    <DIR>          .
06.12.2019  15:38    <DIR>          ..
05.05.2018  20:07        33 556 378 labeledTrainData.tsv
05.05.2018  20:07           282 796 sampleSubmission.csv
05.05.2018  20:07        32 724 746 testData.tsv
05.05.2018  20:07        67 281 491 unlabeledTrainData.tsv
```

i.e. the "problem" file **testData.tsv** IS there, next to the "good" **labeledTrainData.tsv**.

if I change the slash direction for the second line and run it like this:

```
train  = pd.read_csv('tutorial\labeledTrainData.tsv', header=0, delimiter="\t", quoting=3) #OK!
test   = pd.read_csv('tutorial/testData.tsv',         header=0, delimiter="\t", quoting=3) #OK!
```

then both lines run just fine. Same, they run fine if I put **r** before problem file name:

```
test   = pd.read_csv(r'tutorial\testData.tsv',         header=0, delimiter="\t", quoting=3) #OK!
```

I checked both files' attributes - none is hidden , nor read-only, permissions are equal, etc.

Changing lines order in the cell does not change the erorr - same file is problem...

I want to know what the problem **pandas** (or **python**?) sees in the second line of code, which I do not see?

Comment: if you look for a more general solution, have a look at the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module

Comment: Use forward slash `/` or double backslashes instead of backslash `\` in the path.

Comment: Thank you for your review of my question. Yes, like I mentioned originaly, `r`, back-slash `/` - they all work just fine. My question though was why two identical lines of code - one works, the other fails ? What causes the second line throw exception while first line works in the same conditions just fine ?

Answer (score 3):

Python is interpreting `\t` as a tab in the string `'tutorial\testData.tsv'`.

You can change this, as you've found out, by using `r"..."` to indicate it as a [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), which means python ignores backslashes.

Comment: Thank You very much! Seems like that is exactly that! Funny though is to test your suggestion, replaced `'tutorial\testData.tsv'` with `'tutorial\unlabeledTrainData.tsv'` and guess what - of cause, I have got another error of`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 8-9: truncated \uXXXX escape` )) Then I realised that now `\u` in the path string interpreted as a special symbol . Ok, anyway , thanks a lot again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.
`test = pd.read_csv('tutorial\testData.tsv', header=0, delimiter=r'\t',quoting=3)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the full path? (starting from 'C:\')